# Removing duplicate data in SQL Server columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to remove some duplicate date from a table called `[dbo].[FactGunSales]` and the column is `[sale_id]`. I am checking if there are duplicates with the code below which works and then the code below is the code I am having issues with as it returns no rows affected.

```
-- Detecting Duplicate
SELECT [sale_id], COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM [dbo].[FactGunSales]
GROUP BY [sale_id]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
GO

-- Deleting Duplicate
DELETE FROM [dbo].[FactGunSales]
WHERE [sale_id] NOT IN (SELECT MAX([sale_id])
                        FROM [dbo].[FactGunSales]
                        GROUP BY [sale_id])
GO
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

Instead, use `ROW_NUMBER()` or `COUNT(*)`.  Your code seems equivalent to:

```
WITH todelete AS (
      SELECT fgs.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sale_id) as cnt
      FROM [dbo].[FactGunSales] fgs
     )
DELETE FROM to_delete
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Normally, though, you don't want to delete *all* duplicates.  You want to keep one of them.  For that, use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
WITH todelete AS (
      SELECT fgs.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sale_id ORDER BY sale_id) as seqnum
      FROM [dbo].[FactGunSales] fgs
     )
DELETE FROM to_delete
WHERE seqnum > 1;
```

Your query doesn't give an indication about *which* row to keep.  This version keeps an arbitrary row.  You can keep the newest or oldest or biggest or smallest or whateverest by changing the `ORDER BY` clause.

Your version doesn't delete anything because at least one value of `sale_id` is `NULL`.  If *any* value returned by the subquery is `NULL`, then the `WHERE` filters out all rows.  Usually, I strongly recommend using `NOT EXISTS` instead, but for this purpose an updatable CTE makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using a cte and ranking the records on the basis of sale_id, and so any duplicate sale_id would have a rank=2,3,4 etc.. After that you would need to delete entries which are <> rank=1

```
with cte
  as (select row_number() over(partition by sale_id order by sale_id) as rnk
            ,*
       from [dbo].[FactGunSales]
      )
delete
  from cte 
where rnk <> 1
```